# easiest way to add a tooltip without adding more markup

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

What is the most efficient way to add a tool tip to these buttons without adding more markup? Is there a way to add the tooltip content in the javascript instead of markup--. I am using some javascript to basically grab everything inside of the bs-example class so I don't want to add unnecessary markup to the screen.

```css
     .dropdown, .dropleft, .dropright, .dropup{
  position: inherit;
 }
 .dropdown-menu.show {
  width: 100%;
  background: #999;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
  border: none
 }
 .dropdown-menu.show {
  display: inline-flex;
 }
 .dropdown-item {
     display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
/*  color: #333;*/
 }
         .start {
           width:141px;
           padding: 20px;
       }

    .btn {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    .btn-secondary1 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #919ca7;
    border-color: #6c757d;
}

.btn-secondary2 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #7d878f;
    border-color: #6c757d;
}


.btn-secondary3 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6c757d;
    border-color: #5c6268;
}

.btn-secondary4 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4a5055;
    border-color: #6c757d;
}

  .ms-dlgCloseBtnImg {
        border-style: none !important;
        max-width: inherit !important;
    }

    .ms-dlgTitleBtns {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

    .fake-underline{
    text-decoration: underline;

}
                .circular-image {
                                align-content: center;
                                border-radius: 50%;
                                width: 150px;
                                height: 150px;
                            }
                    
                            .accordion {
    position:relative;
    background-color:white;
}

.accordion > input {
    display:block;
    margin:0 0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.accordion > label {
    display:block;
    font:bold 18px/30px Arial,Sans-Serif;
    background-color:#a0aec0;
    color:white;
    margin:-30px 0 0 0;
    padding:0 15px;
}

.accordion > div {
    padding:10px 15px;
    display:none;
}

.accordion > input:checked + label {
    background-color:slateblue;
}

.accordion > input:checked + label + div {
    display:block;
}


.accordion input[type="radio"]:checked + label i.icon::before{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 i.icon{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 25px;
 }
 i.icon::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
 }
 
 i.icon::before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
 }
    .bs-example {
      
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <H2>tester<i style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;margin-left:10px;" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle" v-on:click="showModalZ=true"></i></H2>
            <p>Please select the corresponding rating for each</p>
            <div class="bs-example">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="start">
                        <strong>1</strong>
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="Build" autocomplete="off" v-model="test" value="1">Novice
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="Build" autocomplete="off" v-model="test" value="1">Advanced Beginner
    
                    </label>
                   
                </div>
           
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Easiest" is very broad term. **Read the docs:**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

**The most "basic" steps:**

#### 1/3. include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

#### 2/3. Add data attributes to your markup + title :

```
<label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
      Novice
</label>
```

### 3/3. initialize

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

attribute selectors:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

**Example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<H2>Tooltip</H2>
<div class="bs-example">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="start">
      <strong>1</strong>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="Build" autocomplete="off" v-model="test" value="1">Novice
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="Build" autocomplete="off" v-model="test" value="1">Advanced
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  /* https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere */
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  })
</script>
```

### "Without" any extra markup

Use:
`$().tooltip(options)`
Attaches a tooltip handler to an element collection.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#tooltipoptions

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bs-example label").tooltip({
      title: "Hello tooltip."
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<H2>Tooltip</H2>
<div class="bs-example">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="start">
      <strong>1</strong>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="Build" autocomplete="off" v-model="test" value="1">Novice
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="Build" autocomplete="off" v-model="test" value="1">Advanced
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bs-example label").tooltip({
      title: "Hello tooltip."
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to use `tooltip` is to use existing property than re-inventing the wheel here is in `bootstrap`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="You just hovered!">Hover me</a>
</div>
```